# Issue while injecting arraylist in spring

Tags: java, spring

I am using spring 3.2.2. I am facing issue while injecting a collection(ArrayList) using the util:list tag in spring.I have the below bean defination

```
package com.springaction.testmultidimesionalcollection;


import java.util.List;

/**
 * @author jinesh
 *
 */
public class Address {


    List<Country> country;

    public List<Country> getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
    /**
     * @param country the country to set
     */

    public void setCountry(List<Country> country) {
        this.country = country;
    }


}
```

Below is the spring configuration file I am using.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd"
   >
   <bean id="address" class="com.springaction.testmultidimesionalcollection.Address">
        <property name="country">
            <util:list list-class="java.util.ArrayList" value-type="com.springaction.testmultidimesionalcollection.Country">
                <list>
                    <ref bean="countryChina"/>
                    <ref bean="countryIndia"/>
                    <ref bean="countryAus"/>
                </list>
            </util:list>

        </property>
    </bean>
<bean id="countryChina" class="com.springaction.testmultidimesionalcollection.Country">
        <property name="countryName" value="China" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="countryIndia" class="com.springaction.testmultidimesionalcollection.Country">
        <property name="countryName" value="India" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="countryAus" class="com.springaction.testmultidimesionalcollection.Country">
        <property name="countryName" value="Australia" />
    </bean>
 </beans>
```

I tried to test this with the following code.

```
package com.springaction.testmultidimesionalcollection;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

/**
 * @author jinesh
 *
 */

public class TestMultiDimensionalMain {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ApplicationContext context =  new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("com/springaction/testmultidimesionalcollection/testmultidimensionalcollection.xml");
        Address addrs=(Address)context.getBean("address");
        System.out.println("address size:" + addrs.getCountry().size());


    }

}
```

But I am getting the below exception when it tries to load the spring configuration file.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to required type 'java.util.List' for property 'country'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.util.ArrayList] to required type [com.springaction.testmultidimesionalcollection.Country] for property 'country[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:463)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:494)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:488)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1439)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1398)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1134)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.util.ArrayList] to required type [com.springaction.testmultidimesionalcollection.Country] for property 'country[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertToTypedCollection(TypeConverterDelegate.java:559)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:448)
    ... 17 more
```

I don't understand why spring is giving such kind of exception? Did I missed something in the spring configuration?

Comment: I think `<list>` under `<util:list...` should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `<list>` tag:

```
    <util:list list-class="java.util.ArrayList" value-type="com.springaction.testmultidimesionalcollection.Country">
        <list>
            <ref bean="countryChina"/>
            <ref bean="countryIndia"/>
            <ref bean="countryAus"/>
        </list>
    </util:list>
```

to

```
    <util:list list-class="java.util.ArrayList" value-type="com.springaction.testmultidimesionalcollection.Country">
            <ref bean="countryChina"/>
            <ref bean="countryIndia"/>
            <ref bean="countryAus"/>
    </util:list>
```

Answer (score -1):

Not this

```
<util:list list-class="java.util.ArrayList"
```

but this

```
<util:list list-class="java.util.List"
```